# Rewriting Text.text will behave strangely

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tcp

Rewriting Text.text will behave strangely.

I am using the text of the Text component to display the log on the game screen in Unity. Since there is an asynchronous operation that is received by TCP, Log is put in the queue once, and it is retrieved and displayed in Update method.

```
    private void Update()
    {
            if (LogQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                var msg = LogQueue.Dequeue();
                Debug.Log(msg);
                LogText.text = msg + "\n" + LogText.text;            
            }
    }
```

```
    public void CreateServer()
    {
            var portText = IpInput.text;            
            var port = int.Parse(portText);            
            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,port);
            server.Start();
            server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(AcceptClientCallback), server);
            LogQueue.Enqueue($"Server listening on port {port}");
            LogQueue.Enqueue($"wait client ...");   
    }

    private void AcceptClientCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
            var listener = (TcpListener)ar.AsyncState;
            client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);            
            stream = client.GetStream();

            var msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("connected");
            stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
            LogQueue.Enqueue("connectd");

            var buffer = new byte[128];
            stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ReadStreamCallBack, buffer);      
    }

    private void ReadStreamCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
            Debug.Log("called");
            var buffer = (byte[])ar.AsyncState;            
            var msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            LogQueue.Enqueue(msg);            

            var back = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("received");
            stream.Write(back, 0, back.Length);

            var nextBuffer = new byte[128];
            stream.BeginRead(nextBuffer, 0, nextBuffer.Length, ReadStreamCallBack, nextBuffer);
    }
```

When actually executed, the log of synchronous processing is displayed correctly as shown below.

```
sync log 1
```

```
sync log 2
sync log 1
```

```
sync log 3
sync log 2
sync log 1
```

However, when the log of a message received asynchronously with TCP starts to be displayed, the previous log disappears and only the latest log is displayed.

```
received message 1
```

```
received message 2
```

```
received message 3
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Not surr if related but in general when working with threads you should rather use a thread-save [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1) instead of a simple one. Did you check if there are not maybe some empty lines added so it looks like there is only the last message but the rest maybe disappeared due to your `Text` wrapping settings?

Comment: Thank you!!. In order to check if there are unnecessary line breaks, it was changed to `LogText.text =" ["+ msg +"] \ n "+ LogText.text;`, and the display became `[message`. Certainly there seems to be a lot of unnecessary line breaks. However, to remove this, `LogText.text =" ["+ msg.Replace ('\ n', 'a') +"] \ n "+ LogText.text;` has no change. (Although I once tried using BlockingCollection instead of Queue, it didn't help.)

Comment: Can you check what the text component has as text in the Inspector? Also try [debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) to see what the actual string values are!

Comment: What I thought was a line break was actually the string `\ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 ...`. I was able to notice by trying the debug mode as advised. Thank you!

Comment: this is the so called [Null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) ... I guess it is caused by the buffer not being completely filled so you get some invalid bytes?

Comment: Yes. I received a buffer longer than the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Null Character or receive only the required length.

Removal:
`str = str.TrimEnd ('\ 0');`